# For some reason it keeps loading the same data even though it's supposed to be a fresh 100

Tags: javascript

Every time the load function is called it's supposed to grab the next 100 items from the data array but for some reason, it keeps loading the first 100 items instead of new ones.

```js
  var data=[];
  var cum = 101;
  
  $.get("http://127.0.0.1/l/search.php?query='.$_POST['search2'].'", function(dta) {
    data=dta.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
    for (var item in data.slice(0, 101)) {
      $(".results").append(data[item]+"<br/><br/>");
    }
  });

  $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).height()==$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()){
          console.log("Loading more links...");
            load();
        }
    });
 });

  function load() {
    if (cum+100 > data.length) {
      if (cum != data.length) {
        for (var item in data.slice(cum, data.length)) {
          $(".results").append(data[item]+"<br/><br/>");
        } cum=data.length;
      }
    } else {
      for (var item in data.slice(cum, cum+100)) {
        $(".results").append(data[item]+"<br/><br/>");
      } cum+=100;
    }
  }
```

```html
<p class="results">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`for .. in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops, which traverse indexes 0 to 99. And with that indexes you don't access the slice but the original array

```
for (var item in data.slice(cum, data.length)) {
   $(".results").append(data[item]+"<br/><br/>");
}
```

In this loop, `item` will have the values 0, 1, ..., 99. Then you access `data[item]` which will, of course, always access the first 100 elements of the original array.

The easiest would be, correctly iterating the array with a [`for .. of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```
for (var item of data.slice(cum, data.length)) {
   $(".results").append(item+"<br/><br/>");
}
```

Another possibility would be creating the slice before the loop and then iterating the slice with a simple for loop

```
var theslice = data.slice(cum, data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < theslice.length;i++ ) {
   $(".results").append(theslice[i]+"<br/><br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly simplified way of *probably* doing what you want:

```js
const data=[], inc=20;
// $.get("http://127.0.0.1/l/search.php?query='.$_POST['search2'].'",
for (let i=0;i<500;i++) 
  data[i]=(""+i).padStart(3," ").replaceAll(" ","&nbsp;")+" squared is "+(i*i);

$(".results").html(data.slice(0,inc).join("<br><br>"));

$(function(){
  let cum=inc;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).height()==$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()){
      console.log("Loading more links...");
      $(".results").append("<br><br>"+data.slice(cum,cum+=inc).join("<br><br>"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="results">
</p>
```

I skipped the AJAX part and used some locally generated data.

It is always a good idea to assemble the html string before you `.append()`. Calling `.append()` for each item individually will probably be noticably slower than calling it only once for the complete group of new items.